# How to prevent restarting from orientation change?

Tags: android, multithreading

Here is the structure of my application.

```
MainActivity.java calls FragmentActivity.java,
FragmentActivity.java calls GameView.java
GameView.java calls Thread.java.
```

Basically all the gaming logic will be handled by GameView and its thread.
I don't know how to prevent from restarting the game when there is a orientation change.

If i paused the thread and resume it, the app crashes and also i can not use onSaveInstanceState method in Gameview.java

Any help?

Comment: you shouldn't do it, it is not recommended. If you declare `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"` in the Manifest, you will achieve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is completely possible through the Android manifest.
Just add in the activity declaration, in which you want to disable the restarting the following attribute:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

Then you can overwrite the `onConfigurationChanged()` in your activity and you get the callback which event just happened. In your case the orientation change. And with this approach the activity doesn't restart, when your orientation changes.

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for onResume() and on pause() ... You store values into a bundle in pause and instantiate those values on the resume method and show a dialog as this happens to prevent the user from noticing the obvious.

Answer (score 0):

You can have some control over what happens on orientation change, by defining an [`Application`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) class in your manifest file, and overriding public method [`onConfigurationChanged()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onConfigurationChanged(android.content.res.Configuration)).

> Base class for those who need to maintain global application state.
>   You can provide your own implementation by specifying its name in your
>   AndroidManifest.xml's  tag, which will cause that class
>   to be instantiated for you when the process for your
>   application/package is created.

You just need to check for `newConfig == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE` and such. At this point you might want to reload resources to get things working.